# WCF XML Name Space

Tags: java, c#, .net, wcf

Mi consulta es como poder editar este caso, mi xml al exponer mi WCF me muestra así:

```
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:billService/getStatus" style="document"/>
```

y quisiera saber si podria mostralo asi de esta manera :

```
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:getStatus" style="document"/>
```

Hay alguna forma de editarlo en el WCF?

Porfavor espero alguna respuesta y su ayuda.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Se supone que un servicio de `WCF` lo consumes creando un "Service Reference" no necesitas editar el mensaje `xml` del `SOAP`, para eso te lo abstrae el codigo `proxy`

Si necesita redefinir como se expone deberias analizar el uso de atributos en el servicio, no cambiando el xml soap

Algo como lo comentado aqui, que hace uso del `[OperationContract]`

[How to specify custom SoapAction for WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192588/how-to-specify-custom-soapaction-for-wcf)

analiza usando el

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IXXServiceContract
{
   [OperationContract(Action = "getStatus")]
   void getStatus();
}
```